# How to get current position in Chrome on Android 4.2.2+ devices

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, geolocation

Please: before giving an answer or marking this question as duplicate, please try your code on a recent version of Chrome Mobile

Please: before posting your code, try it on Chrome for Android, not the Desktop version with the mobile User Agent.

I use the following code to get the current position:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          function(position) {
            /* Geocoding based on latitude and longitude */
            // do stuff
            console.log(position);
          },
          function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          },{ timeout: 30000, enableHighAccuracy:false}
  );
} else {
  console.log('permission denied');
}
```

this code always give timeout error. I tried with different combination of options using enableHighAccuracy true or false, giving other options etc.
As you can think, i answer yes when the browser asks me to get the coordinates and in setting i always allow the access to my position.
I have the GPS and Wi-fi turned on and the Google Maps app works fine, but maps.google.com gives the error "Your location could not be determined".
Is this bug documented officially somewhere or there is a method to determine the position?

Look again at the beginning of this question: before marking this question as duplicate or giving easy answers, please try your code on your phone/tablet. 
Using Chrome Desktop (Windows) or Firefox the code above works fine.

Comment: Works fine for me both on mobile and desktop.

Comment: i know it works on Nexus 4, but not on Samsung Galaxy S4. Works on all desktop clients.

Comment: I tested on a Galaxy Note 2, it also worked. Seems like something is wrong with your phone (or maybe just problems with the settings on it).

Comment: It's not only my phone. This behaviour is also reported by some other visitors of the page.

Comment: Do you have a site I can test? I don't have a server I can upload the code to.